# Does add-apt-repository not support globs in source list?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, add-apt-repository

I usually add a repository like this:

```
add-apt-repository --no-update --yes "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy stable"
```

This works fine and when setting up Ubuntu machines, I run a [setup script](https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/blob/d5aedf5/per-host-config/ubuntu/setup.sh#L41-L85) that loops through a [list of repos](https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/blob/d5aedf5e66ca633d40a22484c356f7ddc238ee04/per-host-config/ubuntu/repos.local) and adds them using that command.

The problem is that it fails when encountering a repo source on this format:

```
deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/repo.charm.sh.gpg] https://repo.charm.sh/apt/ * *
```

It will then just fail with `Unable to handle repository shortcut 'deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/repo.charm.sh.gpg] https://repo.charm.sh/apt/ * *'`.

I can, of course, just work around this special case and do as the docs say and just [paste the contents into a file](https://github.com/charmbracelet/glow#package-manager), but I should not have to if Stuff Just Works as it should. So is there something about the format I am not handling correctly when using the utility command or does it simply fail to recognize it due to missing functionality in the internal parsing bits? If not, what do I do to have it not fail?

Comment: It's hard for me to think of a use case for globbing third party deb sources that doesn't end in disaster for the user. For stuff to "*Just Work as it should*," Ubuntu already offers two easy routes: The software could be distributed through the Ubuntu repositories or distributed as a Snap. Diligence checking a new source, in the Debian ecosystem, is a human admin responsibility (not an apt function).

Comment: I have no idea how this applies to this question. The glob thingie is not something I came up with, it is just referenced from the installation docs: https://github.com/charmbracelet/glow#package-manager. In any case, it is supported by the file format, so should be handled by the tooling creating the files as well.

Answer (score 5):

The `*` is not actually a glob, but just a `*`.

However, that's not the problem here. A Python library that `add-apt-repository` uses, `python-apt` (maintained by the developers of `apt`), doesn't support anything except `arch` and `trusted` options for source lines.

From [the source code of the v2.5.0 release](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/python-apt/-/blob/2.5.0/aptsources/sourceslist.py#L189-202):

```py
if pieces[1].strip()[0] == "[":
    options = pieces.pop(1).strip("[]").split()
    for option in options:
        try:
            key, value = option.split("=", 1)
        except Exception:
            self.invalid = True
        else:
            if key == "arch":
                self.architectures = value.split(",")
            elif key == "trusted":
                self.trusted = apt_pkg.string_to_bool(value)
            else:
                self.invalid = True
```

In this case you could just write to a file yourself:

```
printf "%s\n" 'deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/repo.charm.sh.gpg] https://repo.charm.sh/apt/ * *' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/charm.list
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the solution I wrote about above (paste into file) that I ended up using: https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/commit/571e954ad5f5556652facf7a69e161cb0720ebdb#diff-2618323c72aa0cdb8530a40e4ab153ea538218717fa59259e26c45d6140eb2c3R42-R47

Too bad the project is not on Github: makes the threshold for supplying a stray PR that much higher :/ Thanks for the deep dive anyhow :)

Comment: @oligofren in a sense, a stray PR is easier here. [Debian's bug reporting interface](https://bugs.debian.org) does not require an account (and can be operated entirely via email), so you could open a bug there and attach a patch with your proposed fix by email. It's just a different workflow than you're used to.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and for providing some common sense. My experience so far when encountering issues in some Ubuntu or Debian package (like a bad translation in `ls`) is that I never figure out the right upstream or downstream place to provide the patch, so the attempt at providing a fix always just fizzles out, unlike when I can find some GH issue tracker with pull requests and a discussion interface. I _might_ give this one another go :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a known bug at debian, see
[add-apt-repository should use signed-by](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1862764)